# How to differentiate between direct child methods and inherited child methods using reflection?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a unit test to check if direct child methods of a class have an `HttpGetAttribute`. I'm currently unable to differentiate between direct child methods and inherited child methods.

My class in question:

```cs
[...]
public class StatusController : ControllerBase
{
    [...]
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Index() {...}
}
```

My unit test currently:

```
[Test]
public void StatusControllerMethods_HaveHttpGetAttribute()
{
    var controller = new StatusController();
    Assert.That(controller.MethodsHaveAttribute(typeof(HttpGetAttribute)));
}

public static bool MethodsHaveAttribute<T>(this T controller, Type attribute) where T : ControllerBase
{
    var controllerType = controller.GetType();
    var allMethods = controllerType.GetMethods();
    var methodTypes = methods.Select(x => x.GetType());
    var doesntHaveAttribute = new List<Type>();
    foreach (var methodType in methodTypes)
    {
        if (!methodType.GetCustomAttributes(attribute, true).Any())
            {
                doesntHaveAttribute.Add(methodType);
            }
        }
    }

    if (doesntHaveAttribute.Any())
        Console.WriteLine($"The following methods don't have {attribute.Name}:\n{doesntHaveAttribute.Select(x=> x.Name).ToArray().Join(",\n")}");

    return !doesntHaveAttribute.Any();
}
```

The `GetMethods()` method returns all of `ControllerBase`'s methods as well as Index() as I would expect. I need a way to differentiate between inherited and direct children as I would only like to check that there is a `HttpGetAttribute` on direct children of my `StatusController` class.

I have tried various properties, for example `ReturnType`, `IsInherited` with no clear separation of methods.

Comment: [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typeof(T).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.NonPublic
        |BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Static
        |BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

This will get all methods (`public`, `private`, `protected`, ..., static or not) of type `T`.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmethods). Especially relevant to your question is `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`:

> BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly to search only the methods declared on the
>   Type, not methods that were simply inherited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.bindingflags?view=netframework-4.8) when calling `Type.GetMethods()`:

```
var allMethods = controllerType.GetMethods(
    BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.Instance |
    BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```